# How to create uuid4 file names for images uploaded with Django-CKEeditor?

Tags: python, django, file-upload, django-ckeditor

I want to create random uid file names for images uploaded with the django-ckeditor/uploader.

I've created `utils.py` in the same folder as `settings.py`:

```
import uuid

def get_name_uid():
    ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
    return filename
```

I would like to add this "random" file name to `settings.py`:

```
CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = get_name_uid()
```

How can I do this? I am not sure how to get the filename that is uploaded in the editor. Should I pass the filename from settings.py to utils.py? Or is there a different way to do this?

Their documentation says the [following](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor):

````
``CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"``

When using default file system storage, images will be uploaded to "uploads" folder in your MEDIA_ROOT and urls will be created against MEDIA_URL (/media/uploads/image.jpg).

If you want be able for have control for filename generation, you have to add into settings yours custom filename generator.

```
# utils.py

def get_filename(filename):
    return filename.upper()
```

```
# settings.py

CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = 'utils.get_filename'
```

CKEditor has been tested with django FileSystemStorage and S3BotoStorage.
There are issues using S3Storage from django-storages.
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's basically all spelled out for you in the docs:

```
def get_filename(filename):
    return filename.upper()  # returns the uppercase version of filename
```

So the example function `get_filename` gets the uploaded filename passed in and you're supposed to return the filename you want it to be. This is what we call a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

What the callback gets passed in as arguments is called the "*callback signature*" and the docs specify neatly what it gets.

So put the function in a place where it [makes sense](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project). I would choose `mysite/mysite/utils.py` given the structure outlined in the tutorial, under the heading "*Let’s look at what startproject created:*". So in the same directory as `settings.py`. I would name it `generate_uuid4_filename` and `mysite/mysite/utils.py` would look like this:

```
import uuid
import os.path

def generate_uuid4_filename(filename):
    """
    Generates a uuid4 (random) filename, keeping file extension

    :param filename: Filename passed in. In the general case, this will 
                     be provided by django-ckeditor's uploader.
    :return: Randomized filename in urn format.
    :rtype: str
    """
    discard, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    basename = uuid.uuid4().urn
    return ''.join(basename, ext)
```

Now update your `settings.py`:

```
# Near the rest of the CKEditor variables
CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = '<app_label>.utils.generate_uuid4_filename'
```

And you're done. Good luck!

Comment: Internal Server Error: /ckeditor/upload/
module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
[06/Jul/2017 14:48:20] "POST /ckeditor/upload/?CKEditor=id_description&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en HTTP/1.1" 500 97818

Comment: Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Melvyn no idea?

Comment: the docs/example say its a string (also the exception), put the 'module.function' you want to use.

Comment: @Fruch Sorry I don’t understand. What do you mean?

Comment: Apparently I needed to add "CKEDITOR_FILENAME_GENERATOR = '[APPNAME].utils.generate_uuid4_filename'" to settings.py. I did not import anything.

Comment: Still don't understand why this [APPNAME] was necessary :S

Comment: it's needed cause this plugin is doing the import on it's own, hence you need your app name in it, importing it without app name won't work. (explicit is always better than implicit)

Comment: Yep, @Fruch is absolutely right. It needs to be an importable path. Corrected the answer. Apologies for the oversight.